# Ключ шифрования в base64

Tags: java, android, криптография

Генерирую ключи RSA шифрования. Kак правильно сделать из них `base64` для хранения и передачи и как правильно вернуть из `base64` `key` ?
 Если можно, приведите пожалуйста пример кода для android.

```
//генерирую ключ
KeyPairGenerator pairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair keyPair = pairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Key publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        Key privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//ключ в base64 строку
byte[] encodedKey = key.getEncoded();
String base64Key = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedKey);
```